# Detect Browser Support for CSS @Page Property

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I am currently using CSS `@page{ /* some css */ }` to set some specific CSS, however not every browser supports this. I want to use some Javascript to detect if the browser supports this, and if not, display a message to the user.

I read about `CSS.supports()`, but any variation of the command I've tried does not work.

What is written in my file currently is:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  if (!CSS.supports("page")){
    console.log("booooo")
  } else {
    console.log("yaaayy")
  }
});
```

Ideally, I would be able to use the inside of the if statement to add a class to a preexisting html message such as `<p> For best results viewing this webpage, please use Google Chrome. </p>` (The reason I recommend Chrome is because I know Chrome supports @page the feature.)

I am open to other solutions, but since the @page feature is what corrects the page, this method would be future proof because if browsers decide to add or drop support for this feature, this method would still function (assuming no deprecation of `CSS.supports()`).

Comment: Personally I can't find *anything* on how you could detect this directly or even try something like opening a print dialog and reading the computed page styles to see if they match your stylesheet or not. Maybe in this case you'll have to try to detect the browser directly instead of the feature?

Comment: Yeah I read about how detecting features was a good way to go because of the future proofness of it, but just like you, I have not found anything about how to do this either.